# Multiple SQL Transaction within one Express Controller

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

Im stuck at the following problem:

We have the table "Order" and "OrderPosition" as well as "Cart" and "CartPosition". Whenever a order is being executed, a new Order should be created, all CartPositions should be inserted to OrderPosition and all CartPositions should be deleted.

My code kind of works, but SQL transactions take too long, so the data integrity is not ensured. For example, sometimes the same item is being inserted to the table Order 2 or 3 times, because the delete-transaction takes too long.

My Code is:

```
exports.order = async (req, res) => {
    const {CartID} = req.body;
    try {
        var cartInformationen = await db
            .promise()
            .query(
                `SELECT Dienstleister_ohne_TVID, PatientID FROM Cart WHERE CartID = '${CartID}'`
            );
        db.query(
            `INSERT INTO Order (Dienstleister_ohne_TVID, PatientID, created_on) VALUES ('${cartInformationen[0][0].Dienstleister_ohne_TVID}', '${cartInformationen[0][0].PatientID}', current_timestamp())`
            );

        var OrderID = await db
            .promise()
            .query(
                `SELECT MAX(orderID) AS orderID FROM Order WHERE Dienstleister_ohne_TVID = '${cartInformationen[0][0].Dienstleister_ohne_TVID}' AND PatientID = '${cartInformationen[0][0].PatientID}'`
            );
        
            do {
                var cartPositionInformationen = await db
                .promise()
                .query(
                    `SELECT MIN(ArtikelID) AS ArtikelID, OrderQuantity FROM cartposition WHERE cartID = '${cartID}'`
                );
                db.promise().query(
                    `DELETE FROM cartposition WHERE cartID = '${cartID}' AND ArtikelID = '${cartPositionInformationen[0][0].ArtikelID}';`
                );

                db.query(
                    `INSERT INTO Orderposition (ArtikelID, orderID, quantity) VALUES ('${cartPositionInformationen[0][0].ArtikelID}', '1', '${cartPositionInformationen[0][0].OrderQuantity}') `
                );
                var nextArtikelID = await db
                    .promise()
                    .query(
                        `SELECT MIN(ArtikelID) AS ArtikelID FROM cartPosition WHERE cartID = '${cartID}'`
                    );
                    console.log("nextArtikelID " + nextArtikelID[0][0].ArtikelID);
            }
            while (nextArtikelID[0][0].ArtikelID != null)
            res.status(200).send("Order was sent.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res
          .status(400)
          .send({ msg: "Order could not be executed." });
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: Two concepts for you to consider: 1) getting the [autoincremented id of the most recently inserted row](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row).  2. [Multi-query transactions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#transactions).